# Call Back Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two functions , Function `submitCallbackInfo` is callback function in a loop and `XYZ`. I only want to execute `XYZ` once i receive all data from `submitCallbackInfo` without using timeout or jQuery.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var id;
  myHttp1.connect(url, 'GET', data, submitCallbackInfo);
}

setTimeout(XYZ, 5000);
```

What i exactly want is to call `XYZ` function only when `submitCallbackInfo` executes 10 times.

Comment: Please explain the question in detail with more code.

Comment: If you are using a lot of callbacks in javascript, i find it easy to use the async library, it contains the [waterfall function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) which i think would fit your needs very well.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable – I would suggest `Promise.all()`, in such scenario...

Answer (score 1):

> Check the value of `counter` in the `callback` function

```
var length = 10;
var count = 0;

function submitCallbackInfo() {
  if (++count === length) {
    createC2VCall();
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  myHttp1.connect(url, 'GET', data, submitCallbackInfo);
}
```

`Promise` could be used if `myHttp1.connect` returns a `Promise-object`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to @[Rayon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon)'s answer, you can pass count as parameter. You can use `.bind()` to do it.

Following is a basic implementation

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10;) {
  //myHttp1.connect(url, 'GET', data, submitCallbackInfo.bind(++i));
  test(submitCallbackInfo.bind(null, ++i))
}

function submitCallbackInfo(count){
  var maxCount = 10;
  console.log('Inside Callback', count)
  // Do your stuff
  if(count === maxCount) XYZ();
}

function XYZ(){
  console.log('Inside XYZ')
}

function test(callback){
  if(callback) callback();
}
```